# Time complexity with arbitrary number of nested loops

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I am just learning the concept of time complexity and for the following nested loop what will be the time complexity?

```
i:1-n loop 
   j:N(i) loop
    stmt;
   end

   k:M(i) loop
    stmt;
   end
end
```

In the above pseudocode, the main i-loop is executed for n times. The nested loops j and k run for an arbitrary number of times which is stored in an array N and M.  N(i) and M(i) are bounded by n-1.

For example, let n =3 and N=[2,1,3] and M=[2,3,3].
Then the inner loops will be executed for 2+1+3 times and 2+3+3 times. How do I formulate time complexity for this? Will saying O(n^2) be correct?

Comment: `i:1-n` or `i:n-1`?

Comment: I meant i loops from 1 to n

Comment: Ok, and `j:N(i)` probably means from 1 to `N(j)`. In that case, did my answer help answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know that *N(i)* and *M(i)* are bounded by *n-1* for any *i*, you can draw the conclusion that your inner loops will be bounded by ***O(n)*** iterations.

So you get a total time complexity of:

***O(n * 2n) = O(n<sup>2</sup>)***

of `stmt` calls.

Comment: Let's say for example, n=10, N=M=[1,2,1,1,2,3,1,2,1,3]. Then, the total time complexity is much less than O(n^2), since Big 0 notation is the average time complexity right?

Comment: @lakdee Big-O is not average time complexity. Big-O is just complexity. You can use it for average, worst, best, time, space... Also notice that *n = O(n^2)* and even *n=O(n^100)*. For this reason, it is correct to say it is *O(n^2)*. With the information you gave in the question, *n^2* is also the best time complexity we can guarantee. If you do know that your elements are bounded by a constant *k*, then yes, it becomes *O(k * n) = O(n)*.